# overview of issues in arabic and similar languages with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, arabic

Maybe it is too broad question for stackoverflow, however, I will ask it:

With which issues you should be able to deal with when working with such languages as Arabic and similar languages? Can you give me some list of them?

I have recently started a project in Sindhi. I do not speak arabic, sindhi or similar language, I am writing "left to right". However, I have a project for sindhi users. And I would like to know which issues I should deal with when creating this project.

So, basicly using my system users can add some articles in sindhi, upload pictures etc. I need to create/edit/delete those things from MySQL database and fetch all data. For now, I do not need some searching in text or similar things, just simple CRUD operations.

1) I understand that this is rtl language and I need to use dir="rtl" in HTML.

2) For those class of languages, it should be necessary to use UTF-8 encoding and ut8_general_ci collation in database.

3) When quering data with PHP, you should use mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");

4) Are there any other special issues to deal with when using CRUD operations in mysql? 
I have found out that there could be problems with text search in mysql. I have found http://www.ar-php.org/en_index-php-arabic.html website about special set of classes for arabic in php, however, I need only CRUD operations for now, do I really need some special classes or I can work like in "english based" PHP / MySQL?

What else do you suggest?

Comment: Make sure you have the .php file that outputs any of the data saved as utf-8 format

Comment: start with utf-8 data, use exclusively utf-8 data/transmission/storage. if anything comes in that ISN'T utf-8, convert it right away.

Comment: with the points that you outlined, everything should be fine, I am always dealing with RTL (UTF-8) languages, I don't have any issue... Just be aware when using PHP string functions for  UTF8...

Comment: Please see edit on answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else in MYSQL except that you cant use full text search.

In PHP you need to use mb_string functions for doing any operation on texts.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

There is no problem with CRUD too.

I am Iranian and my language is Persian which is similar to Arabic in writing and I can confirm that you don't need any thing special. :)

*Edit: Forgot to say, You need to use this meta tag in your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also dont forget to save your php and html files in utf8, but you can use this tool in case you cant do that somewhere:
http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html