# MySQL; select some left character from field

Tags: mysql, substr, summarization

when i want to select 100 left characters of a field, i use this syntax:

```
SELECT LEFT (text, LOCATE(' ', text, 100)-1) AS title FROM myTable
```

This query has no problem for me.
But today i want to use this on a Unicode text and this query don't work correctly.
For example: if my field contains `ماهي كيفية قضاء صوم رمضان الذي لم اصمه ؟` as text, the above query return empty string.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REVERSE()` of MySQL. The manual of the reverse are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse).

On the other hand, you have to choose right `UNICODE` collation for your columns/tables.

I am referring you to another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649699).

Comment: `reverse` is just another MySQL function. i know most of MySQL string function but i don't know how to use them for the purpose.